# HTMLUnit Open Window showing google.com

Tags: htmlunit

I need some very simple help to open google.com in a browser from a Java desktop app.

Looking at using HTMLUnit and something like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
```

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebWindow;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.RefreshHandler;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTable;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTableRow;

public class HTMLUnit {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
```

// Create and initialize WebClient object
     WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_8);

```
        webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
 webClient.setRefreshHandler(new RefreshHandler() {
```

public void handleRefresh(Page page, URL url, int arg) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("handleRefresh");
   }

```
 });

        Page NewGooglePage = webClient.openWindow(new URL("http://www.google.com"), "GoogleWindow").getEnclosedPage();
```

When running this file in NetBeans should I get a window to pop?

Answer (score 3):

No,

HtmlUnit is a "headless browser". It means every things you do with HtmlUnit are not visible.

Instead I suggest you try WebDriver/Selenium 2 (http://seleniumhq.org/docs/09_webdriver.html). With WebDriver you can remote control browser like Firefox or IE.

Something like:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.RenderedWebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class GoogleSuggest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // The Firefox driver supports javascript
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // Go to the Google Suggest home page
        driver.get("http://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en");

        // Enter the query string "Cheese"
        WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        query.sendKeys("Cheese");

     }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you for this response this is great and exactly what I think I need.  Does it mean though that the client will need FireFox installed to run the app?

Also, I'm actually looking to access the google adwords keyword tool within my app and as it has the captcha I needed to pop up a browser so the user can enter the captcha.

As you have said in your code "The Firefox driver supports javascript", would this then mean I can use Javascript to popup a window just showing the captcha to enter?  The only thing I can see being a problem here would be session cookies but maybe not.

Comment: Yes, you need to have the actual browser you are "remote controlling" installed on the computer running webdriver.
The rest of your comment looks like a hack (and I'm not sure it is compatible with Google terms of use), so good luck ;)

Comment: Oh I just tested your code above and it doesn't seem to pop a window open??

Comment: for some reason I'm getting a can't find element error.  I have tried different By methods like ClassName, ID, TagName, Name etc. I get the same error for all when running the above code:

Comment: see my new question in the answer field above about being unable to locate element

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Google use AJAX to display results so you may have to use wait* methods in order to wait for the AJAX to be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

...this may be related to the parameters send in the request. I compared the ones send by HTMLUnit and the original browsers. There are differences. By the way you can add the missing request paramters in HmlUnit.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly this code worked, I changed to the IE browser, seems something is up with FireFox.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;



public class KeywordTool {
    private static final By By = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // The Firefox driver supports javascript
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

        // Go to the Google Suggest home page
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // Enter the query string "Cheese"
        WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        query.sendKeys("Cheese");

     }
}
```